# Dois números não somam, eles concatenam

Tags: javascript, jquery

Vocês já devem estar carecas de ver problemas iguais a este. O meu problema, acredito eu, é um pouco diferente.

Eu tenho um método (chamado de transformaParaContas) que transforma qualquer tipo de valor monetário para ser possível calcular. Porem, mesmo transformando, eu não estou conseguindo utilizar estes números para somar. Fiz um método para verificar se o retorno do transformaParaContas realmente é numérico, e sim, sempre da true.

Metodos:

```
function transformaParaContas(value){
    if(value.indexOf(".") >= 0){
        value   =   value.replace(/\./g, "");
    }

    value   =   value.replace(",", ".");
    value   =   Number(value);
    value   =   value.toFixed(2);
    return value;
}

// metodo para verificar se é realmente um número 
function isNumber(numero){ 
    return !isNaN(numero);
}

// disparo
$("input[name='txt_valNaoProcedente']").on("keypress", function(){
    var valProc, valNaoProc, total;
    valProc     =   $("input[name='txt_valProcedente']").val();
    valNaoProc  =   $("input[name='txt_valNaoProcedente']").val();
    if(valProc != "" && valNaoProc != ""){
        valProc     =   transformaParaContas(valProc);
        valNaoProc  =   transformaParaContas(valNaoProc);

        console.log(isNumber(valProc));
        console.log(isNumber(valNaoProc));

        total       =   valProc + valNaoProc;

        $("#div_valorDebito").text(valProc + valNaoProc);
    }else{
        $("#div_valorDebito").text("");
    }
});
```

Se eu fizer o seguinte, funciona:

```
$("input[name='txt_valNaoProcedente']").on("keypress", function(){
    var valProc, valNaoProc, total;
    valProc     =   $("input[name='txt_valProcedente']").val();
    valNaoProc  =   $("input[name='txt_valNaoProcedente']").val();
    if(valProc != "" && valNaoProc != ""){
        valProc     =   transformaParaContas(valProc);
        valNaoProc  =   transformaParaContas(valNaoProc);
        valProc     =   Number(valProc);
        valNaoProc  =   Number(valNaoProc);

        console.log(isNumber(valProc));
        console.log(isNumber(valNaoProc));

        total       =   valProc + valNaoProc;

        $("#div_valorDebito").text(valProc + valNaoProc);
    }else{
        $("#div_valorDebito").text("");
    }
});
```

Alguém saberia me explicar o porque isso acontece?

Comment: Já tentou Parsefloat? https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: Desculpe, não ficou claro. Utilizar o Parsefloat aonde?

Comment: Na função transformaParaContas, ao invés de fazer Number(value), tente parseFloat(value). Teste sem o Tofixed se nao funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caro amigo, a função `toFixed(n)` sempre irá retornar um o tipo `string` por isso que há a concatenação e não a soma dos seus valores. E é por isso que quando você usa `Number` funciona.

Para uma mudança menos dramática por assim se dizer, considere retorna a valor sua função `transformaParaContas(value)` já como número, que seria um `return Number(value);`

Outra coisa, que é apenas uma curiosidade, mas que vale sempre a pena está de olho, você criou uma variável `total` que nunca está sendo usada. *Considere remover, ou melhorar o seu código como por exemplo:*

```
$("input[name='txt_valNaoProcedente']").on("keypress", function(){
    var valProc, valNaoProc, total = ""; // Valor já iniciado
    valProc     =   $("input[name='txt_valProcedente']").val();
    valNaoProc  =   $("input[name='txt_valNaoProcedente']").val();
    if(valProc != "" && valNaoProc != ""){
        valProc     =   transformaParaContas(valProc);
        valNaoProc  =   transformaParaContas(valNaoProc);
        valProc     =   Number(valProc);
        valNaoProc  =   Number(valNaoProc);

        console.log(isNumber(valProc));
        console.log(isNumber(valNaoProc));

        total       =   valProc + valNaoProc;
    }
    $("#div_valorDebito").text(total);
});
```

Comment: Excelente! Era esse mesmo o problema, obrigado.